# alternate of html tag required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on a project, where there seems to be an issue with the [poll](http://morth.nic.in/morthpoll.asp):

On the site, I have created an opinion poll, on which I have included 5 options, with each option having two corresponding radio buttons for yes/no.  I want to make sure that user has selected one radio button for each of the statements/questions, so I used the attribute "required" on the input, however, it did not seem to work:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="">Close all liquor shops near and on the National Highways. This will also reduce drunken driving on Highways.</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        Yes<input type=radio name="close" id="close" value=1 required>
        No<input type=radio name="close" id="close" value=2>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have also tried the following instead of the "required" attribute:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="">Close all liquor shops near and on the National Highways. This will also reduce drunken driving on Highways.</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        Yes<input type=radio name="close" id="close" value=1 required="required">
        No<input type=radio name="close" id="close" value=2>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I also tried the attribute `data-required required`, however that also didn't work.

For each of the examples that I tried that worked, they each worked in one browser (e.g. Chrome), but didn't work in IE.  A few others that I tried did not work at all.

Comment: "This will also reduce drunken driving on Highways" - this seems to be a hypothesis, or at the least an unsupported assertion (please cite your sources if you're going to make such statements, otherwise your poll/study would seem unnecessarily flawed). Also, try to avoid leading questions, this question would leave respondents who like being able to shop for alcohol en-route in a quandary about also supporting death by dangerous driving/DUI.

Comment: I know David. but what to do i am working on application for govt. of India.
and can't make any changement in the data given by client. i can only suggest that i already done let see what there response is.

Comment: Really? How does one bid for work for the Indian government..? =D

Comment: don't know dear but it's a great project for me as you can check it by following the given link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, I'd suggest (and please bear in mind I don't agree with what you're doing (forcing a user to make a choice) *or* the available choices to the (horribly) leading, and coercive, questions):

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
        // in this version we're only using it once, so caching may not be necessary
    var self = $(this),
        // finds the radio input elements:
        radios = self.find('input[type="radio"]'),
        /* iterates over the radio elements, creates an array of their names,
           discards the duplicates: */
        groups = $.unique(radios.map(function(){
            return this.name;
        }).get()),
        // gets all the checked radio elements:
        checked = radios.filter(function(){ return this.checked; });

    /* if the checked length is not equal to the number of 'groups',
       there are some left unchecked: */
    return checked.length === groups.length ? true : false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/c8yMu/).

Notes:

HTML: has been corrected to the following:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="">Close all liquor shops near and on the National Highways. This will also reduce drunken driving on Highways.</label>
                </td>
                <td>Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="close" value="1" />No
                    <input type="radio" name="close" value="2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="">Electronic watch on the National Highways to check speed limit of vehicles. Speed governors should also be installed in the vehicles.</label>
                </td>
                <td>Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="ewatch" value="1" />No
                    <input type="radio" name="ewatch" value="2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="">Data base of road accidents on National Highways and effective data collection mechanism.</label>
                </td>
                <td>Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="data_collection" value="1" />No
                    <input type="radio" name="data_collection" value="2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="">Stricter punishment for traffic offenders on the Highways and license cancellation of repeat offenders. There should be an online review of license status.</label>
                </td>
                <td>Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="punishment" value="1" />No
                    <input type="radio" name="punishment" value="2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="locality">People should follow lane system. It will lead to a reduction in the number of accidents</label>
                </td>
                <td>Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="follow" id="follow" />No
                    <input type="radio" name="follow" id="follow" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Duplicate `id`s have been removed, the `checked` attributes have been removed (since you want to enforce user-interaction, don't offer pre-checked options, it makes no sense); I left the empty `for` attributes alone, but the `label` for the `input`s should be the `yes`/`no` text (since that's what'll be clicked to interact with the options available. This would require a unique `id` for *each* `input` (as would the HTML *specification*), or you could simply nest the `input` within the `label` element, giving something like the following:

```
<label>Yes <input type="radio" name="close" value="1" /></label>
<label>No <input type="radio" name="close" value="2" /></label>
```

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute=value]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`jQuery.unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `checked="checked"` instead of required.. This will select a default option if the user does not choose anything.

Comment: no no sudeep the [srs] which we have bond me not to allow user leaving any option blank or unchecked if user clicks on my google+poll have to fill the form. @sudeep

Comment: Instead of forcing the user to make a choice, this makes it impossible to distinguish (in processing of form data) whether the user made the “yes” choice or did not make any choice.

Comment: sorry jukka i can't make change in srs given to me.
so plz tell soln if u can. no change in functionality

Answer (score 0):

The `required` attribute in any radio button means, by HTML5, that the user must check one of the radio buttons in the group into which the button belongs. Both variants used, `required` and `required="required"` are allowed and mean exactly the same. There are several problems with your code, but this feature is correct in both versions.

The issue here is that not all browsers support the `required` attribute.

You might consider adding JavaScript code that checks whether one of the radio buttons is in the checked state when the form is to be submitted. Naturally this won’t work when JavaScript is disabled. And someone could create a modified copy of the form and use it to submit data. Therefore, the server-side form handler should verify the data, without assuming anything about client-side checks.

Regarding methodologies of surveys, forcing people to make choices distorts data: users will just stop answering or they will make choices at random if they wish to proceed. Thus, a better strategy uses (at least) three radio buttons, for yes, no, and does’t want to answer, and then perhaps tries to force the user to make a choice between these (thereby accepting an explicit “doesn’t want to answer” but not entirely skipping the question).

Comment: can  you hint me the code i mean that javascript function. as the function i am making is not working.